# How do I get these tags in hover element using Python + Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, getattribute

I'm using Python and Selenium to parse a web page. I want to get the numbers 45, 77, and 298 from this element:

```
<li id="guru" rel="popover-srs" title="" 
data-content="<ul><li>Radicals<span>45</span></li><li>Kanji<span>77</span></li><li>Vocabulary<span>298</span></li></ul>" data-original-title="<div class='srs-logo guru'>
</div>">
<span>420</span>
Guru</li>
```

These numbers appear only when you hover over with the mouse. Even though I found the element like so:

```
print(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'guru').text)
```

I get just the output:

```
420
Guru
```

How do I get the numbers in the span values (45, 77, 298)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are looking for is inside the `data-content` attribute of that element, not a text content.
What you can do here is to get the `data-content` attribute value and then to extract these values form there.
Something like the following:

```py
data_content = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'guru')get_attribute("data-content")
parts = data_content.split('<span>')
for index, part in enumerate(parts):
    if index > 0:
        part = part.replace('<span>','')
        partitions = part.split('</span>')
        print(partitions[0])
```

Comment: You are welcome, my friend :)